# When adding more items to top of scrollview shift existing items down

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add an item to the top of the scrollview while shifting down all existing items.  I dont want to remove the existing views and re-add them.

This is how I'm building my scrollview:

```
for var index=0; index < data.users.count; index++
 {
  if data.users[index] as! String != ""
   {
    let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    myImageView.image = myImage
    myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
    myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
    myImageView.frame.origin.x = 0
    myImageView.frame.origin.y = MyVariables.yPosition
    self.myScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)

    MyVariables.yPosition += imageHeight + spacer
    MyVariables.scrollViewContentSize+=imageHeight + spacer

    self.myChatScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: MyVariables.scrollViewContentSize)
}}
```

Is there a way I can shift the exisitng items down on my scrollview when adding a new item to the top?

```
// on button click, I want to shift everything down and add the new item on top 
// without removing the current views
```

Comment: You need to update the origin of the frame of each subview to move them down.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this kind stuff better you should be using TableView which handle all the things better when you add remove and items.

If your requirement is to use scroll view then you need to do it step by step .

- First you need to move you items down by changing the frame origin (y) to do this.

  -Run a for loop for all the subviews and make your view frame y + height of new one.
- Also make sure to handle All the constraints if you are using auto layouts.
- **If you handle you constrains better really don't need to move all the items if you move top one rest will be handled**.
- Add new item with animation when you done with moving other items.